# Cannot get multiple ssh keys to work with BitBucket using aliases

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I have two bitbucket accounts, one for my personal stuff and one for work. My personal one was working fine and the one I use at work also works fine; however I wanted to be able to connect to the work one from home but I am having trouble getting it to work.

**My files are called:**

```
## Unrelated ones I use for plan.io that still work

id_rsa
id_rsa.pub

## Personal one for bitbucket I just created because of seperation

homeid
homeid.pub

## Work one for bitbucket

workid
workid.pub
```

**My config file is as:**

```
Host home@bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/homeid


Host work@bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid
```

Now I got a little confused on how to do the cloning with the aliases, but tried:

```
git clone work@bitbucket.org:my-username/myrepo.git
```

But it fails with the error message:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have added the publick keys to the appropriate bitbucket accounts so not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok worked it out.

I was using the incorrect git clone address, the correct one being:

```
git clone git@workid:my-username/myrepo.git
```

...but also had to change my *config* file to the below to change the hosts:

```
Host homeid
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/homeid


Host workid
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid
```

Answer (score 1):

> Host home@bitbucket.org

The [ssh_config](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) `Host` directive doesn't accept the "username@" syntax. Use the `Match` directive instead:

```
Match user home host bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/homeid
...
```

Comment: So how do I do the clone? With `git clone home@bitbucket.org:my-username/myrepo.git` ?